# Do non-deponent Latin verbs ever have a "middle voice"?

Tags: example-request, passive-voice, deponent-verbs, voice, middle-voice

In Ancient Greek, verbs often take a "middle voice", neither active nor passive. [The forms usually look identical to the passive on the surface, but can take direct objects and cannot take an agent (unlike true passives).](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/11257/406) Some verbs only ever occur in the middle voice, with no active forms at all!

To a Latin-speaker, this should sound somewhat familiar: verbs which look passive on the surface, but can take direct objects, can't take agents, and have no active forms? That fits the deponent verbs (*sequor*, *hortor*, *arbitror*, etc) perfectly. In other words, the deponent verbs seem to act like the Greek middle voice, rather than the Latin active or passive.

But in Ancient Greek, pretty much *any* verb can be put into the middle voice, not just the deponents.

Was this true in any attested stage of Latin? That is, do we ever see non-deponent verbs with passive morphology, but able to take accusative direct objects and not able to take ablative agents?

Comment: Does gaudeo count?  Or does it have to have active and passive forms in the same tense?

Comment: @CMonsour The same tense would be ideal, but that's still worth noting!

Comment: Some Latin verbs (e.g. doceo) that take 2 accusative objects in the active can retain one of those accusative objects in the passive (so-called 'retained accusatives'). But doceor can take an agent too, because it's passive, not middle, in *meaning*. For a middle *meaning* in Latin, passive and reflexive forms can be used (e.g. movetur/se movet, 'It's moving'); but to my knowledge, additional accusative direct objects are never used in these instances.

Comment: @cnread The passive voice of verbs with two accusative objects was studied in [an earlier question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/129/79). Some ideas from there might indeed be useful in this discussion.

Comment: As for your question, “do we ever see non-deponent verbs with passive morphology, but able to take accusative direct objects and not able to take ablative agents?”, what about exs. like _neque mei neque te tui intus puditumst factis quae facis_ (Pl. _Bacch._ 3, 1, 12)?  As for your grammatical conditions, (i) there is an accusative direct object (_te_), (ii) no ablative agent is possible here, and (iii) the verb has passive morphology but is not "prototypically" deponent as such, though it is true it can be considered as semi-deponent in competition with _puduit_ (cf. also C Monsour's point).

Comment: *puditum est* is simply an impersonal verb like *decet, vīsum/necesse est*.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian: Yes, _puditum est_ is (simply?) an impersonal verb (cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/what-is-the-grammatical-logic-of-impersonal-constructions-like-me-non-solum-p ). But what is relevant here is not impersonality but to find verbs (impersonal or not) that obey the grammatical conditions described in the question (i.e., to find "non-deponent verbs with passive morphology, but able to take accusative direct objects and not able to take ablative agents").

Comment: @Mitomino The asker is looking for something that can be described as "middle voice". *puditum est* is a semi-**deponent** impersonal verb, and impersonality is incompatible with the definition of middle voice, which requires a subject.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Were you satisfied with the answer to your own, earlier Q; you did not seem to be? Any thoughts on this one; would be delighted to receive (further) enlightenment.

Comment: @tony I was happy with it; I wouldn't have accepted it otherwise. I just wanted some additional clarification, but on that topic the level of clarity I was after might be impossible. I've been thinking whether I should write something to answer this one, but I don't have any thoughts coherent enough yet.

Comment: @Draconis: In the Q: "The forms....can take direct objects and cannot take an agent..". Joonas, in his earlier Q., gave: "tu rem doceris a me." The verb has a subject (tu), a direct object (rem) and an agent (me). How does this fit in?

Comment: I wonder: why are you requiring the *grammatical form* of the Latin middle to be a **passive** one? Another option which exists in some modern Latin languages and also in Polish is to use a **reflexive** construction to express the middle: *zjedz ciastko* “eat a/the cake” vs. *zjedz sobie ciastko* “eat yourself a cake”. I would be curious to know whether *sibi* is ever used as a middle-izing particle.

Comment: @MartinKochanski Good question! Mostly because the deponent verbs, the only ones I can think of with definite middle meanings, use passive morphology.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Took your advice and used material from your earlier Q. I did ask about "tu rem doceris a me" contrasting with "middle-voice" verbs.

Comment: As for the connection with reflexivity, same in Italian: e.g., cf. _Lucia si è compratA un'auto_ & _Lucia ha compratO un'auto_ ("Lucy has bought a car").  The presence of a reflexive pronoun _si_ in the former requires BE auxiliary and participle agreement with the subject _Lucia_. In contrast, the latter, without reflexive, requires HAVE auxiliary and there is no participle agreement with the subject.

Comment: By the way, Draconis, I've just realized that the **title** of your question, as it stands, can be interpreted too broadly: e.g., for some people reflexive constructions like _Valvae se ipsae aperuerunt_ (Cic. Div. 1, 74) ‘The doors opened by themselves’ involve an instantiation of **non-deponent** verbs in "**middle** voice", understood in a broad sense. In contrast, your question at the end, the one I've considered in my answers, is more precise ("do we ever see non-deponent verbs with passive morphology, but able to take accusative direct objects and not able to take ablative agents?").

Comment: @Mitomino Very true; I unfortunately had to abbreviate the question in the title to keep it within the length limit.

Comment: @Draconis. Ok! Putting the connections between reflexivity & middle voice aside (I guess something interesting could be said on this issue mainly in Late Latin), I've just revised my answer to your intriguing question. Hope you consider a bit convincing since I'm afraid it's my last push on it...

Answer (score 4):

Thinking about your very interesting question ("That is, do we ever see non-deponent verbs with passive morphology, but able to take accusative direct objects and not able to take ablative agents?"), here is an example that could be argued (at least, claimed!) to satisfy your grammatical conditions:

> *flava caput **nectentur** oliva* (Verg. *Aen*. 5, 309)
>
> 'They shall have their head(s) crowned with yellow olive' [Source of Engl. transl.](https://books.google.es/books?id=kCZICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=flava%20oliva%20nectentur&source=bl&ots=L2Glt9DQUH&sig=ACfU3U2mL9UjOxUiayEoVjNUnM4IzgDZiA&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia8a3Jg-3jAhUE2-AKHRRfALUQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=flava%20oliva%20nectentur&f=false)

(i) there is an accusative direct object. NB: *caput* is often regarded as an "accusative of relation" (aka "**Greek** accusative", which, by the way, nicely relates to your present question) but HERE, in this use, it can also be claimed to occupy the **direct internal argument** slot of the verbal predicate. Accordingly, it can be claimed to be more properly regarded as a "**retained** accusative of specification" in the sense that it can be analyzed as the corresponding direct object of an active sense (*caput nectent*; please see this link for the notion of ["**retained** accusative of specification"](https://books.google.es/books?id=kCZICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%22perfudit%20umeros%22%20135&source=bl&ots=L2Glt9DLNN&sig=ACfU3U0Ct3YWZsCrw55s9JT0vBpuGJEpog&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwja98y8ge3jAhUKi1wKHYxSC5AQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22perfudit%20umeros%22%20135&f=false)).

(ii) no ablative agent is possible here due to its "middle" meaning, and

(iii) the verb has passive morphology but it is not a deponent verb (NB: nor a prototypical one nor a "peripheric" one like the semideponent use of *pudet/**puduit*** in my comment above).

Comment: Verb "necto" (not the most appropriate for "to crown") appears to be passive future of a nominative: the head(s) will be crowned. What's the difference between that and e.g. agricola videtur; pueri audiuntur; donum datur; agricola nectetur? Are you sure that "caput" is an accusative?  Recall "vinum est Bibendum" (the wine: it-ought-to-be-drunk); some, with an instinctive desire to treat "vinum" as a direct object (accusative) and not a nominative, which it is.

Comment: @tony: As for the English translation of _nectentur_, I agree with you this is not a literal one (since it is not mine I previously added the source link. In any case, please note that the literal translation is not always the "most appropriate" one). As for _caput_, yes, I'm sure that it is accusative. Notice that it can only be accusative (as nominative, it would be _capita_, in agreement with 3rd plural of _nectentur_).

Comment: Mitomino: Yes, in the English translation, plural "head(s)" was optional; should have written "caput/ capita". Could yourself, please, explain how caput/ capita nectentur differs from a nominative noun + passve-verb; thus, becoming an accusative + passive-verb? The "flava oliva" = "with yellow oil" is easy; but, having separated "flava oliva", all that remains is "caput (capita) nectentur". This, in grammatical terms, is the same as the examples e.g. agricola nectetur, I gave earlier.

Comment: @tony: Perhaps it can be useful to point out that the nominative plural subject of _nectentur_ is mentioned in the previous verse: _tres primi_ ('the first three'). Since _caput_ is singular accusative but the verb _nectentur_ (3rd.pl) is passive -and passive verbs don't **generally** have direct objects-, a natural conclusion seems to be that _caput_  is an "accusative of relation". This said, my point is that one can claim that HERE _caput_, the alleged accusative of relation, is in fact occupying the direct object position of the verbal predicate: cf. "retained accusative of specification".

Comment: Thank you. Put an attempt at understanding in Answers.

Answer (score 4):

The way I see it, there is no middle voice in Latin, but there can certainly be traces of it.
The situation is similar to the dual number.
That said, looking for such traces is interesting.
Here is one candidate worth considering.

Dictionaries tend to list [*contemplare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=contemplo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) and [*contemplari*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=contemplor&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) as separate entries.
However, if we analyze them as the same word, something resembling a middle voice arises.
The passive forms are not passive in nature, and they can take accusative objects as mentioned in the linked L&S entry.

The slight difference in meaning sounds suitable for a middle reading.
Namely, *contemplo* is roughly "I observe" whereas *contemplor* is more "I consider" which could be seen as "I observe for myself".
For practical purposes the verbs are essentially synonymous, but one can contemplate whether the deponent verb arose from something middle.
L&S mentions that the active forms are ante- and post-classical.
Perhaps the passive forms took over and there was no need to use the active forms in parallel if the distinction was minor or non-existent.

Plautus appears to be the only writer to use both active and passive forms to any significant extent, so it is worthwhile to take a look at [his 15 uses of *contempl-*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23contempl+%5Bpl%5D).
Upon a quick inspection, I get the feeling that the active forms are more "look" and the passive ones "think".
This gives some support to the idea of a middle.
(But I won't stretch the analysis too far with just these data points or claim that it is absolutely so.)

**So, perhaps the deponent verb *contemplari* could be seen as the middle voice of *contemplare*.**
This is not the only verb which has normal and deponent versions.
Perhaps analyzing more such pairs could reveal more solid evidence for middle, if these kinds of cases count as middle for you.
I happened to be reminded of this particular pair in [a recent question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11276/79).

Comment: llmavirta: Does yourself agree with Mitomino's analysis of "flava caput nectentur oliva", above, or not?

Comment: @tony I agree that there is indeed a trace of something like a middle there in a plausible reading. I don't know if there's anything in Latin that I'd call "truly middle", but similar phenomena do appear. The point of my answer was to add to the variety of middle-like constructions and let the folks decide what's most appropriate or interesting.

Comment: @tony: I think that my **last** example (see below: _nuda genu nodoque sinus **collecta** fluentis_) is in a sense even better as an answer to Draconis's question (hence my third try!). It's "better" in the sense that the accusative-of-relation interpretation of _sinus fluentis_ is a bit contrived here (cf. the body part _caput_ in the previous example (_caput nectentur_), where such an interpretation is in fact the "typical" one). If so,  it seems that _sinus fluentis_ is the true direct object of _collecta_, which behaves like a Greek **middle** participle.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta. After reading your very interesting answer on different meanings of _contemplo_ and _contemplor_, I was wondering if for native speakers of Latin there was an (indeed, very subtle, if any!) semantic difference between, for example, the impersonal variants _puduit_ and _puditum est_. Cf. my comment & example above (my first try!): _neque mei neque te tui intus puditumst factis quae facis_ (Pl. _Bacch_. 3, 1, 12). After all, many functionalist linguists consider it, at least, as a default hypothesis that a difference in form involves a difference in meaning.

Comment: @Mitomino: Every time I read this, something new registers! In "...with bare knees having been gathered in a knot of flowing robes..."; isn't "sinus fluentis" a genitive phrase": of-the-flowing-robes? But the thing (flowing robes) referred to by the action (having-been-collected [collecta]) gives the "accusative-of-relation"--is that correct?

Comment: @Mitomino: Me again, please. In "valvae se ipsae aperuerunt" the verb is not passive; though the meaning is--does this affect "middle-voice" qualification? When the subject of an indirect statement is the same as the subject of the main verb, a reflexive pronoun must be used. The "participle bit"  of the infinitive must agree with the pronoun, which will be in the accusative e.g. "dixi me venturum esse". Reflexivity gives the accusative/ direct objects; but, as in "Lucy buys herself a car", the verbs are active. Is participle agreement with the subject (I-said that-I-would-come) enough to

Comment: @Mitomino: Continuing: establish "middle-voice" character?

Comment: @tony: notice that "fluent**i**s" is a poetic/archaic variant of accusative "fluent**e**s" (cf. https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/4t4ddb/whats_this_about_accusative_plurals_ending_is/ ). As for the (ab)use of "middle" term,  perhaps it can be useful to take a look at https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8815/on-the-typical-ambiguity-of-porta-clausa-est  & https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/how-things-change-in-latin

Comment: @Mitomino: I translated incorrectly: " ...and bare knees joined in a knot TO flowing robes"; giving "sinus fluentis (fluentes)" as an accusative ("the true direct object of collecta").

Comment: This comment discussion is getting sidetracked and has little to do with the answer about *contemplari*. Please take the discussion to our chat room or ask a new question about the details. This topic is certainly worth exploring in more questions.

Answer (score 2):

Third time lucky! Here is then my third try in answering Draconis's intriguing question ("do we ever see non-deponent verbs with passive morphology, but able to take accusative direct objects and not able to take ablative agents?"). Consider the following example:

> Namque umeris de more habilem suspenderat arcum
>   venatrix dederatque comam diffundere ventis,
>   nuda genu nodoque sinus **collecta** fluentis.
>
> (Verg. *Aen* I, 318–320)

Notice how the "Draconian" conditions above are fulfilled:

(i) *collecta* has passive morphology but is not a deponent verb.

(ii) there is an accusative direct object (*sinus fluentis*), and

(iii) no ablative agent is possible here due to its "middle" sense.

It seems that there are two ways of analyzing the nominal phrase *sinus fluentis*: (A) it is the true direct object of *collecta*, which behaves like a Greek middle participle ([see this philological comment on verse 320](https://books.google.es/books?id=JKBIrIOR4PcC&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=sinus%20collecta%20fluentis%20middle&source=bl&ots=y1x8NqSB0f&sig=ACfU3U2OhZD_hPV1Ce6g1c5yrngNVyuPwQ&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf-saC2vnjAhVNTsAKHZDYDCMQ6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=sinus%20collecta%20fluentis%20middle&f=false) // see also [Allen and Greenough: 247](https://books.google.es/books?id=gVmMCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247&dq=sinus%20collecta%20fluentis%20middle&source=bl&ots=w0O5uy_KPE&sig=ACfU3U2kLtE3LL2AwcjDUT1x1mAfRD_ucw&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf-saC2vnjAhVNTsAKHZDYDCMQ6AEwD3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=sinus%20collecta%20fluentis%20middle&f=false)) and (B) it is an "accusative of relation" ([see second alternative on verse 320](https://books.google.es/books?id=mfGycd-8lx0C&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=sinus%20collecta%20fluentis%20middle&source=bl&ots=y81WIIWg6U&sig=ACfU3U31x-8lvu9YaqB3mA2yiMRpl9jmng&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf-saC2vnjAhVNTsAKHZDYDCMQ6AEwEHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=sinus%20collecta%20fluentis%20middle&f=false)), perhaps in nice symmetry with *genu* in the previous Adjectival Phrase *nuda genu*. See also the very interesting comment on verse 320 made by the eminent classical scholar [Robert Seymour Conway](https://books.google.es/books?id=EVpkAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=sinus%20collecta%20middle%20greek&source=bl&ots=uf1vimoXZ0&sig=ACfU3U28mY6vBeXpi1khjj0-YgN-qqrEfA&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBkdKk5PnjAhVZhlwKHdy9ClgQ6AEwDXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=sinus%20collecta%20middle%20greek&f=false).

In case you think (as I do, not without some hesitation) that HERE the two abovementioned possibilities (A and B) can be conflated into only one, I can conflate the present answer into my previous one (for the time being, I'll leave them as two different (but related) possibilites of answering the present question). So far what seems clear (at least to me!) is that Draconis's very interesting question can only be answered with examples that, unsurprisingly, turn out to be clearly influenced by Greek.

Comment: This Q has certainly generated some labour! One (hopefully) final point, please. A middle-voice verb can take a direct-object/ accusative; but not an agent. Why not? If we can slay one sacred cow, why not another? Why can't Joonas's "tu rem doceris a me" qualify.

Comment: Continuing: our favourite phrase could be: "flave caput nectentur oliva, a rege", could it not?

Comment: The passivization of _docere_ is a case different from the "middle" example we're discussing here. Notice, for example,  that you can add an agent ablative phrase in _Tu rem doceris a rege_ (cf. _Rex docet te rem_) but you can't do it in _Tres primi flava oliva caput nectentur (*a rege)_.  Remember that in the relevant middle example the (elliptical) nominative subject is _tres primi_ ('the first three'), which is the agent and patient of the action (hence its middle sense). The incompatibility with _a rege_ is then very clear.

Answer (score 1):

As comments-section grows, this is not so much an answer as an interpretation of Mitomino's "flava caput nectentur oliva": the assertion that "caput" is an accusative; not a nominative.

Expressions like "accusative-of-relation" & "retained-accusative-of-specification" can be baffling to those who have not studied linguistics. Extra study is required: "accusative-of-relation" denotes the thing or person (caput) referred to by the action (nectentur) rather than the object proper.

Greek: a retained accusative is based on the supposition that such constructions are converted from active to passive verb-forms and that the accusative is retained from the active construction.
At this point it may be appropriate to study Joonas's earlier Q. Here, Brianpck adapted "te rem doceo" = "I teach you something" to give "rem a me doceris" = "you (subject) are taught (passive) something (retained accusative) by me (agent).
In the passive construction, the accusative-of-the-person becomes the subject; the accusative-of-the-thing is retained.

In the OP's original Q., a "middle-voice" verb is not to take an agent. If the person doing the crowning had been identified, that soul would have been the agent (ablative): "flava caput nectentur oliva, a puella"; presumably, the use of an (ablative) agent restricts the verb to passive-use only; therefore, disqualifying its elevation to the "middle-voice" genre?

This links into "caput" being a "direct internal argument" of "the verbal predicate". The internal argument of a verb has to be realised inside the maximal projection of that verb. The one closest to the verb (here, "caput") is the "direct internal argument"; the other/s--"indirect internal argument" (here, "flava oliva").

The argument-structure of English transitive verb, "open", has an EXternal argument (the Agent) and two internal arguments (theme & instrument) e.g. "Tom opened the door with his key", where "door" is the "direct internal argument" (closest to the verb, "open") & "with his key",  the INdirect internal argument.

Hebrew: Psalm 3:8  "For you have stricken all of my enemies with respect to the cheek";
here, "cheek" is an indefinite primary-noun (no specific or named owner: "his", "John's") and functions as an "accusative-of-specification"--it specifies/ clarifies the verb--the striking is limited to the cheeks, of the enemies. 
Alternative translations identified "adverbial-accusatives" (just to add to the "accusative" confusion) "on the cheek" & "upon the cheekbone"; how the striking was done.

Of course, this is not a retained "accusative-of-specification"; but, it helps to explain arcane terminology.

Applying to the Latin: the crowning will be limited to the heads, suppose it would be, by definition! Hence, the thing or person (the heads) referred to by the action (the crowning).

The conclusion: "caput" in "flava caput nectentur oliva" is an accusative.

(Have not studied Greek, or Hebrew, but they seem to  involve similar concepts, on this topic.)

Comment: Yes, my claim is that in this particular example _caput_ is occupying the direct internal argument position since it can be understood as a "retained accusative of specification" (see the link in my answer). In fact, it is **_caput_** what turns out to be _nexum flava oliva_. Cf. also _necte **comam** myrto_ (Ov. _Am._ 1, 2, 23).