# Using perfect participle as perfect active participle

Tags: translation-explanation, participle, spinoza

Is perfect participle, in spite of the general notion, used both as perfect passive participle and perfect **active** participle?

Spinoza, Ethics, De Dei, Propositio 15, Scholium:

> nam omnes qui naturam divinam aliquo modo **contemplati** sunt, negant Deum esse corporeum

White translates it:

> for all men who **have** in any way **looked** into the divine nature deny that God is corporeal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a deponent verb.
Both the normal *contemplare* and the deponent *contemplari* exist and mean roughly the same thing.
I have the impression that the deponent one is more common, but the details surely depend on the era and author.
The deponent verb has passive forms but active meaning, and therefore the passive perfect participle has active meaning too.
The active counterpart of *contemplati sunt* would be *contemplaverunt*.

Comment: How can I know that a verb is deponent or not?

Comment: @AliNikzad Actually, that'd make a nice new question: By looking at a dictionary entry, how do I know when a verb is deponent?